# How to check if I'm on the last page of posts?

Tags: categories, loop, pages

I want to display some text on the last page that isn't displayed on the other pages.

For example, on category pages: url.com/category/categoryname/page/6

or last page of all posts listed on the homepage: url.com/page/9

How do I check if I'm on the last page?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17):

The `WP_Query` object contains [a `max_num_pages` field](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.2/wp-includes/query.php#L2637) which contains how many pages of posts there are. You can compare the current page number with it. (This is [how `get_next_posts_link()` does it](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.2/wp-includes/link-template.php#L1585).)

```
global $wp_query;
$current_page = $wp_query->get( 'paged' );
if ( ! $current_page ) {
    $current_page = 1;
}
if ( $current_page == $wp_query->max_num_pages ) {
    // You are on the last page
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - I ended up using: `<?php if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages == get_query_var('paged') ) : ?>     <div>TEXT</div><?php endif; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

In short: If you want to learn more about pagination, I've written a [Plugin](https://github.com/marke123/Easy-Pagination-Deamon) for that.

In detail: You can take a look at the `global $paged;` global. But best would be to digg into the plugin code i linked and look at the  `render()` function.